# how to handle login sysetm with php script to the database?

Tags: php

i am trying to build a simple login system  with php , but it dosent send the the user data to the data base i an using XAMPP as a server, **plz check my code**...

here is my **dbh.inc.php** - the file that connect to the server.

```
<?php 

$dbservername="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";
$dbname="loginsystem";



$conn= mysqli_connect($dbservername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
```

and here is my php script **signup.inc.php**
 that handle that send the data to the data base and tell it to put it in the pre table that i have set from the beginning

```
<?php


if  (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; 

$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']); 
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']); 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); 
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']); 
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']); 




// inset the form data to the data base . 


    $sql= "INSERT_INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last' , '$email', '$uid' , '$pwd');";
   mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   exit(); 
// error handlers 
// check for empty fields. 


}


else {
header("Location: ../signup.php"); 
exit();

}
```

Comment: This is a great time to do some debugging.  For example, what does `mysqli_query` return?  What does `mysqli_error` tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to correct the query statement

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last' , '$email', '$uid' , '$pwd')";
```

`INSERT INTO` instead of `INSERT_INTO` and remove the `;` after the `)`

Comment: Yes, and also if your user id is auto incremented, you will want to leave that blank. You should also be encrypting the passwords (see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)